# setting up https proxy on elastic beanstalk

Tags: apache, .htaccess, amazon-web-services, proxy, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to setup a proxy through an .htaccess file to send requests through to another server, like so:

```
RewriteRule ^thisurl/(.*)$ https://anotherdomain.com/thaturl/$1 [P]
```

This works perfect on a regular ec2 instance configured. However, I needed to enable mod_ssl through apache and set SSLProxyEngine On in the apache config.

Is there any way to do this with elastic beanstalk, or am I SOL? All I get is a 500 Internal Server Error in beanstalk. Doesn't seem to be a way to do this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that EC2 instances instantiated by Elastic Beanstalk work behind a Load Balancer. HTTP requests go through nginx in the balancer to one of your EC2 instances. Maybe this is not a problem in your case, but be aware.

As for the `mod_ssl` and extra Apache configuration you can do exactly the same through `ebextensions`, as explained here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers.html

Comment: Thank you, I wound up going with another infrastructure setup, however I will try to use ebextensions in the future.